# Could approved edits be immediately visible to whoever approved it without waiting for other peer-reviews?

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, questions, edits

I was reviewing an edit to a question and I though the edit was improving in many ways the original post (mostly by indenting the code properly).

So I accepted the edit and it was still pending for one more review from peers.

I then went back to the question and the original post was still there. I had to stay on the review page so I could see the nicely formatted question.

That made me wonder: *would it be possible for an edit that I approved to be immediately visible on the original post without waiting for other peer review?*

After all, if I reviewed positively an edit, why am I not able to see it right away and why do I have to wait for other peer-reviews?

Comment: @Deduplicator: None of the questions linked as a duplicate do answer correctly to my question (as they have no answer yet).

Comment: Posts on Meta don't have to be answered to be useful as duplicate-targets. Which is the reason that restriction is not applied to meta.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Fair enough, I didn't know about this. Do you have a link to support this?

Comment: Simple solution, there is almost always something more that can be improved with an edit, if there is a lot more then reject and edit, if there is only a little more then improve edit. Either way, the edit is then automatically rejected/approved and no other users need to waste their review votes.